# How to find database details from a SAS libname

Tags: sas

I have a SAS libname defined like this:
LIBNAME test ODBC DSN="test_odbC" schema=dbo;
How do I find the actual database server ip and password and user and port?

Comment: If you're using a local version of SAS, check the ODBC settings in the control panels, assuming Windows. The set up will have the information in there.

Answer (score 0):

If are working on a client server environment with Management Console, you have two ways to check, Note that all saved passwords in SAS are encrypted.

**Option 1:**

Open SAS Management Console, Right click on the library you want to check, and choose  display libname.

**Option 2:**

If you can't see the connection details in the LIBNAME then:

- In SAS Management Console check the Database connection details, and note the DATASRC name,
- From Administrative tools open your ODBC Driver and check the matching Data Source,
- You will be able to find the server name and user used to login. 
  [image]